# Reading mp3 file duration in Chrome with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have an 'browser application' where users should be able to drag and drop local mp3 files to Chrome and should see some mp3 info (without uploading files to server)...
So far, I can successfully read and display mp3 tags (with JavaScript-ID3-Reader library), but I'm struggling a bit with displaying mp3's duration. Is it possible to get that info with js/jQuery only? If not, what would you recommend for resolving this simple problem?

Code I'm using to handle dropping files to browser looks like this:

```
function initialize() {
    var target = document;
    if (target === null) {
        return false;
    }

    target.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log(files);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            processFile(files[i]);
            objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
            console.log(objectURL);
        }
    }, true);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: if the file is not uploaded, you will not be able to find out the duration reliably. you will have the same problem with the meta data, since you can't upload just the first x bytes in a browser AFAIK

Comment: Hmm, well it seems that I can read mp3 tag without any problem with that library I'm using... But you want to say that it is impossible to get mp3 duration without actual upload to server??

Comment: ah, i'm sorry, i got it wrong. you might be able to du this easily for files with a constant bitrate. you should be able to get the bitrate from your id tag library. then you can simply divide filesize by bitrate to get a close estimate of duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest browsers that support audio tag, you can load the mp3 in an `<audio>` element and access the duration property via the DOM.

To load a audio file to browser see: [window.URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL)

Comment: When I try to add a line `objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);` and `console.log` that, I just get `blob:http%3A//localhost/402b0bff-6c6a-43c7-9aff-66789ecb999e`... Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: And must free it up by window.URL.revokeObjectURL()

Comment: Ah, ok I see... I should pass this URL I got to source of `<audio>` element... OK, got it now, seems it works nice, will test it a bit more...

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var audio = new Audio()
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  console.log(audio.currentTime)
})
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
  console.log(audio.duration)
})

target.on("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.currentTarget.files[0]
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    audio.src = objectUrl
    $("#duration").html(audio.duration)
})
```